# why 2D array is better than objects to store x-y coordinates for better performance and less memory?

Tags: performance, memory

Assuming I want to store n points with integer (x,y) coordinates. I can use a 2-d (2Xn) array or use a list / collection / or an array of n objects where each object has 2 integer fields to store the coordinates.
As far as I know is the 2d array option is faster and consumes less memory, but I don't know why? Detailed explanation or links with details are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use a 2D n*n array to store only n points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, and kinda has many parts to it.  First off, this is relative to the language you are working in.  Lets take Java as an example.

When you create an object, it inherits from the main object class.  When the object is created, the overhead comes from the fact that the user defined class inherits from `Object`.  The compiler has to virtualize certain method calls in memory so that when you call `.equals()` or `.toString()`, the program knows which one to call (that is, your classes' `.equals()` or `Object`'s `.equals()`).  This is accomplished with a lookup table and determined at runtime with pointers.

This is called virtualization.  Now, in java, an array is actually an object, so you really don't gain much from an array of arrays.  In fact, you might do better using your own class, since you can limit the metadata associated with it.  Arrays in java store information on their length.

However, many of the collections DO have overhead associated with them.  `ArrayList` for example will resize itself and stores metadata about itself in memory, that you might not need.  `LinkedList` has references to other nodes, which is overhead to its actual data.

Now, what I said is only true about Java.  In other OO languages, objects behave differently on the insides, and some may be more/less efficient.

In a language such as C++, when you allocate an array, you are really just getting a chunck of memory and it is up to you what you want to do with it.  In that sense, it might be better.  C++ has similar overhead with its objects if you use overriding (keyword `virtual`) as it will create these virtual lookups in memory.

Answer (score 0):

All comes down to how efficiently you'll be using the storage space and what your access requirements are. Having to set aside memory to hold a 10,000 x 10,000 array to store only 10 points would be a hideous waste of memory. On the flip side, saving memory by storing the points in a linked list will also be pointless if you spend so much time iterating the list to find the one point you actually need in the 10,000,000 stored.

Some of the downsides of both can be overcome. sparse arrays, pre-sorting the list by some rule so "needed" points float to the top, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, With a multidimentional array say AxB, you just have a chunk of memory big enough to hold A*B objects, and when you look up an element (m,n) all you need to do is find the element at location m*A+b.  When you have an list of objects, there is overhead associated with every list, plus the lookup is more complex than a simple address calculation.

If the size of your matrix is constant, a 2D array is the fastest option.  If it needs to grow and shrink though you probably have no option but to use the second approach.